# Using QTcpSockets through different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

Following scenario:

I create some `QTcpSockets` in my main thread and save the objects in a singleton (`std::vector<QTcpSocket*>` and a getter for it); if the user press the "StartMeasure" button I start a new thread to avoid blocking behaviour in GUI!

There I start again n new threads for hardware communication (need parallel flow for reasons of speed) -> send/receive something and evaluate the response. (use the getter to the QTcpSockets stored in the singleton)

**Thread Model:**

[image: Thread Model]

If I do it like this I got this warnings:

```
QSocketNotifier: socket notifiers cannot be enabled/disabled from another thread
```

and sometimes this error:

```
_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Should I work here also with signals on QTcpSockets between threads or how can I solve this? (don't want to post the code because I only need a strategy/hint how to do it right)

Thank you!

Comment: How about not using threads in the first place? :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement inter-threading interaction in Qt you can use one of the following techniques.

First, you can simply connect signals and slots of QObjects livinig in separate threads with `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::AutoConnection` attribute. Then, the Qt will promote signal in one thread to slot in other thread using its own event loop system.

Second, you can call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::AutoConnection` from one thread to QObject in other thread. The Qt will again promote that call for invokation in the other thread.

Actually you cannot call directly from one thread methods of network objects (e.g., QTcpSocket), QTimers and some others that use Qt event loop system and live in other threads.

**UPDATE**

Just note, the above aprroaches are applicable only if there is a `QEventLoop` running in the target thread (not sure, maybe for signals/slots apptoach it is a must for both threads). `QThread` provides the one by default if you don't reimplement `run()` or call `exec()` manually in your overriden `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience creating QT sockets in one thread and reading/writing from/to them from another thread is not a good idea, as you can experience multiple issues like the one you got, and crashes. I would suggest you to actually instantiate sockets (call constructor) in the thread that you will use them. Another idea which seems not good is to instantiate sockets in one thread and move to another. Though it usually works for other classes, this obviously doesn't do it 100% correctly for sockets due to some internal and probably system implementation. So I experienced crashes especially when I tried to delete sockets even asyncronously (using `deleteLater`) and using thread synchronization, caused by `readyRead` called on a deleted socket.

So please consider changing your architecture to create/delete sockets in the thread you use them and even avoid storing pointers (smart ones and raw) to them in another thread (at least not to rely on their validity).

I hope these hints will help you avoid the pain I had with sockets and multithreading.